# Using calli to invoke a member function

Tags: .net, reflection, cil, reflection.emit

I would like to call a member function of a .NET object using `calli`. I can invoke a static function that takes an int and returns an int just fine using the following code:

```
// push the int argument
// push the address obtained using Ldftn
ilg.EmitCalli (OpCodes.Calli, System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall, typeof<int>, [|typeof<int>|])
// correct result now on stack
```

I was hoping that I could use something like the following to call a member function that also takes an int and returns an int. "CIL Programming" by Jason Bock suggests it should work, though I am probably reading it wrong. Reflector also thinks something is not quite right, and claims the call is obfuscated. Its best guess is "`return (int) *ptr1(num1);`", which is the same thing is says for the static call:

```
ilg.Emit (OpCodes.Ldarg_0)            
// push the int argument
// push the address                                    
ilg.EmitCalli (OpCodes.Calli, System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall, typeof<int>, [|typeof<int>|])
```

When I invoke the second fragment, I get the following message. Needless to say, I am not using marshalling or anything like that.

> The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error
>   was at 0xed470d3f, on thread 0x20e50. The error code is 0xc0000005.
>   This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable
>   portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user
>   marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the
>   stack.

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation for `calli`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.calli.aspx), the overload of `EmitCalli()` you're using should be used only for calling unmanaged code. For managed code, you should call an overload that takes one more parameter and set it to `null` (unless you're using `varagrg`, which is extremely rare):

```
ilg.EmitCalli (OpCodes.Calli, System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.HasThis, typeof<int>, [|typeof<int>|], null)
```

Comment: Many thanks. Actually, the second argument has a different type in that overload, but this works: EmitCalli (OpCodes.Calli, System.Reflection.CallingConventions.HasThis, typeof<int>, [|typeof<int>|], null)

Comment: @user2129056 Right, fixed.

Comment: @svick could you give a full example for this? I am struggling to get a `calli` working for an instance method pointer found via MethodInfo.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPtr(). E.g. `calli instance !!TResult (!!T1, !!T2)`